# JUnit @Rule lifecycle interaction with @Before

Tags: java, junit, lifecycle, rules

I have some JUnit tests that use the `TemporaryFolder` `@Rule`. They use the `TemporaryFolder` in a `@Before` method to perform some setup:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Before
public void init() {
  folder.newFile("my-file.txt");
}

@Test
public void myTest() { ... }
```

Most of the time this works perfectly. However, when using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` I find that in some cases the `init()` method is invoked before the `Statement` inside my `TemporaryFolder` instance is applied. Because of this, the temporary folder location is unset (i.e: `null`)  when `folder` is used within `init()` and my file ends up in the working directory, not `/tmp`.

So in some cases `@Before` methods are executed ahead of the rules, however, I can't establish a definite pattern. I occasionally see a similar problem with some of my own rule implementations.

Is there any way that I can ensure that my rule statements are applied before any setup methods?

Answer (score 12):

In JUnit 4.10, BlockJUnit4ClassRunner (the superclass of SpringJUnit4ClassRunner) appears to take care to construct Statement chains in such a way that rules run before any @Before methods. From JUnit 4.10:

```
protected Statement methodBlock(FrameworkMethod method) {
    // ...
    Statement statement= methodInvoker(method, test);
    statement= possiblyExpectingExceptions(method, test, statement);
    statement= withPotentialTimeout(method, test, statement);
    statement= withBefores(method, test, statement);
    statement= withAfters(method, test, statement);
    statement= withRules(method, test, statement);
    return statement;
}
```

JUnit 4.7 appears to stitch Statement chains together in a different order:

```
Statement statement= methodInvoker(method, test);
statement= possiblyExpectingExceptions(method, test, statement);
statement= withPotentialTimeout(method, test, statement);
statement= withRules(method, test, statement);
statement= withBefores(method, test, statement);
statement= withAfters(method, test, statement);
return statement;
```

spring-test-3.0.5's parent POM seems to indicate that it depends on JUnit 4.7. I wonder if getting it to use a newer JUnit would help?

Comment: Good find @pholser. I'm using JUnit 4.8.x and that does appear to construct the chains in the same order as 4.10. However, the methodBlock() is overridden in SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and sets a different order similar to that of JUnit 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've used the following as a quick workaround:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tmpFolder = new TemporaryFolder() {
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        if (getRoot() == null) {
            super.before();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public File newFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try {
            before();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t.getMessage(), t);
        }

        return super.newFile(fileName);
    }

    @Override
    public File newFolder(String folderName) {
        try {
            before();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t.getMessage(), t);
        }

        return super.newFolder(folderName);
    }
};
```

This ensures that the `TemporaryFolder` is initialized properly, regardless of whether the `@Before` methods are run before or after the rules.