# How can I make JUnit 4.8 run code after a failed test, but before any @After methods?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, junit4

I'm driving a suite of Selenium tests (actually WebDriver-backed Selenium) using JUnit 4.8.2. I'd like the tests to automatically take a screenshot of the browser as soon as the test fails an assertion. All the tests inherit from `SeleniumBaseTestCase`, and the majority then further inherit from from `SeleniumBastTestCaseWithCompany` (which uses `@Before` and `@After` methods to create and then clean up common test data via Selenium).

I've tried adding a subclass of `TestWatchman` as a `@Rule` in `SeleniumBaseTestCase`, overriding `TestWatchman`'s `failed` method to take the screenshot. The trouble is that the `@After` methods cleaning up the test data are being run before `TestWatchman`'s `failed` method is called, so the screenshots are all of the final step of the clean-up, not the test that failed.

Looking into it a little, it seems that `TestWatchman`'s `apply` method just calls the passed `Statement`'s evaluate method (the only exposed method), which calls the `@After` methods, leaving `TestWatchman` (or any other `Rule`) no chance to insert any code between the execution of the test and of the `@After` methods, as far as I can tell.

I've also seen approaches that create a custom `Runner` to alter the `Statement`s created so that methods annotated with the custom `@AfterFailure` are run before `@After` methods (so the screenshot can be taken in such an `@AfterFailure` method), but this relies on overriding `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`'s `withAfters` method, which is deprecated and due to become private, according to the [documentation](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html#withAfters%28org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.junit.runners.model.Statement%29), which suggests using Rules instead.

I've found another answer on SO about the [@Rule lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738881/junit-rule-lifecycle-interaction-with-before) that makes it sound like this simply might not be possible in JUnit 4.8, but may be possible in JUnit 4.10. If that's correct then fair enough, I'd just like confirmation of that first.

Any thoughts on an elegant and future-proof way in which I can achieve what I want would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in your analysis, @Befores and @Afters are added to the list of Statements before any Rules. The `@Before` gets executed after the `@Rule` and the `@After` gets executed before the `@Rule`. How you fix this depends on how flexible you can be with `SeleniumBaseTestCaseWithCompany`.

The easiest way would be to remove your `@Before/@After` methods and replace them with an [ExternalResource](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html). This could look something like:

```
public class BeforeAfterTest {
    @Rule public TestRule rule = new ExternalResource() {
        protected void before() throws Throwable { System.out.println("externalResource before"); }
        protected void after() { System.out.println("externalResource after"); }
    };

    @Test public void testHere() { System.out.println("testHere"); }
}
```

this gives:

```
externalResource before
testHere
externalResource after
```

This field can be put into your base class, so it gets inherited/overridden. Your problem with ordering between @After and your rules then goes away, because you can order your rules how you like, using [@RuleChain](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html) (in 4.10, not 4.8).

If you can't change `SeleniumBaseTestCaseWithCompany`, then you can extend `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`, but don't override withAfters, but override [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner#methodBlock()](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html#methodBlock%28org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod%29). You can then call super.methodBlock, and reorder the Statements as necessary[*].

[*]You could just copy the code, and reorder the lines, but withRules is private and therefore not callable from a subclass.

Comment: Yep, I think upgrading JUnit is the way to go - I can't see a particularly satisfactory solution in 4.8.2.
I've got a protected TestWatcher on `SeleniumBaseTestCase` to take screenshots, and a RuleChain with that as the sole rule. Then in `SeleniumBaseTestCaseWithCompany` I have an ExternalResource to create/delete the company, and I shadow the superclass's RuleChain ordering both the screenshot and create/delete rule. Seems to work nicely, thanks.

Comment: Just a note. In 4.11, you'll be able to specify @Rule on a method, so you can override that method rather than shadowing a field. But 4.11 hasn't been released yet.